# why spring boot schedule logs not showing in docker.?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I created spring boot service with docker. I used @Scheduled method and write method to print fibonacci series within 10seconds gap.
[from eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmT15.png)

it works fine with my eclipseIDE and showing in console that required output, but not work well with docker.
[from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grqdk.png)

I run it with docker run and also with docker run -d
both times I experienced the same error.
not only for scheduled tasks, its not working for commandLineRunner functions as well.

here is my application properties file

```
logging.level.com.priyan.algoservice=INFO
```

Java 21
Spring boot 3.2.3
Docker version 25.0.3

is there anything missing from my setup.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply proper log configurations and use log framework like log4j, slfj etc.
then make sure to append your logs in to console or different log file
start docker service with -d then try docker logs <image_id>
also you can check inside of the image using 
docker exec -it  bash
then find your log file and tail that